# Finding the line of intersection from a single position vector

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to break through the following `Vectors` related question which isn't too hard but can't seem to get a small portion of it.

### Question

Find the equation of the line *l1* passing through the points A and Bwith position vectors $-i + 4j + 2k$and $2i+j+8k$ respectively.

The line *l2* intersects and is perpendicular to *l1* and passes through the point C with the position vecotr $-i+3k$, find its equation. Find also the distance of the point C from the line *l1*

---

The equation of the line *l1* turned out as follows: $$[-i+4j+2k] + t[3i -3j +6k]$$

However proceeding to find the line of intersection with just point C wasn't getting through my head.

Comment: Draw the diagram friend. It might assist you...

Comment: @SufyanNaeem - Tried getting direction vectors AC and BC but didn't seem to work either, going to see if I can solve it out

Comment: How can we find distance between a line and a point? as in ur case u said that I have to find the distance between point C and line $l_1$.There may be a mistake.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem - By making use of the respective formula $\frac{ax_{0} + by_{0} + c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$.

Comment: I don't see there any formula! It is an expression perhaps!

Comment: **Hint**:Let $H\in AB$ so $H=tA+(1-t)B$, then write $(H-C,AB)=0$, that's it. You find $t$ and then $H$. Then $CH$ will be $l_2$ and $|CH|$ the distance.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin - Could you clarify the very first part of comment. H is an element of AB?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I didn't get you also!

Comment: @SufyanNaeem: OK, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be intersection of $l_1$ and $l_2$.
We have $A=−i+4j+2k$ and $B=2i+j+8k$ ,so the equation above $X=[−i+4j+2k]+t[3i−3j+6k]$ iff $X\in AB$ we could write down as follows:
$$X=tA+(1-t)B$$
By writing $X\in AB$ I mean $X$ is a point on $l_1$ (i.e. "line AB") passing through $A$ and $B$.
Since $H\in AB$ we get $H=tA+(1-t)B$. $HC$ is perpendicular to $AB$ so $(H-C,B-A)=0$. This equation is linear over $t$, we solve it, find $t$, get $H$ from $H=tA+(1-t)B$ and $|H-C|$ will be the distance.
Sorry for my English, can anyone edit how it should be?